# PHP SFTP using phpseclib and filename with wildcard

Tags: php, wildcard, sftp, phpseclib

Im trying to get a file from "yesterday", but the hour/min/sec can be different from day to day.

A file name could be eg:

```
ProductFeed_2017-05-09T23-00-05.csv
```

or

```
ProductFeed_2017-05-10T23-00-04.csv
```

So I need some kind of wildcard for the last part of the file name.. I have tried of couple of different ways, none of the worked so far.

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('domain.dk');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
    echo "error";
}
$date = (int)date("d") - 1;

$filename = 'ProductFeed_'.date("Y").'-'.date("m").'-'.$date.'*.csv'; // T23-00-04.csv

echo $sftp->get('import/'.$filename);

?>
```

Comment: You are correct.. and the methode worked perfect for me. Thanks

Comment: I did, but when I accepted that it was duplicate, your first comment disappeared

Comment: Ahh maked sense, didnt see it was your answer in that thread